# How to splice() an element from subarray?

Tags: javascript

```
var row = [["1", ".", "3", '1', 1], ["1", ".", "3", '4', 5], ["2", "7", "5", '4', 0]];

var newArray = row.splice([1][2], 1);
```

I am trying to take only the third element from the second subarray.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Do you want splice to actually remove the item from the array permanently, or do you just want to index into the array to retrieve an item? Either way, the index needs to be on the row array: `row[1].splice(2, 1)`. Thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 1):

Select the second element before you call splice:

```
var row = [["1", ".", "3", '1', 1], ["1", ".", "3", '4', 5], ["2", "7", "5", '4', 0]];

var newArray = row[1].splice(2, 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var row = [["1", ".", "3", '1', 1], ["1", ".", "3", '4', 5], ["2", "7", "5", '4', 0]];

var newArray = row[1].splice(2,1);
   


console.log(newArray);
```